# How do I use flutter epub viewer with text selection capabilities and customizable selection menu

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I want help in using flutter epub viewer with text selection capabilities and customizable selection menu. I tried using a pdf reader but It was too slow, so I want to use an epub viewer.So that I can select any text and get a customization selection menu.